# How to get only the whole number without rounding-off?

Tags: python, integer

how do you get only the whole number of a non-integer value without the use of rounding-off? I have searched for it and I seem to be having a hard time.

For example:

---

`w = 2.20`

`w = 2.00`

---

`x = 2.50`

`x = 2.00`

---

`y = 3.70`

`y = 3.00`

---

`z = 4.50`

`z = 4.00`

---

Is it as simple as this or that might get wrong in some values?

`x = 2.6` or `x = 2.5` or `x = 2.4`

`x = int(x)`

`x = 2`

---

Is it really simple as that? Thanks for answering this stewpid question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: It will only be wrong if your number deviates less than the numerical precision from the next `int`, e.g. `int(3-1e-16)` return `3`, where as `int(3-1e-15)` return `2`

Answer (score 2):

you can   just divided it into (1)
but use (//) like this:

x = x // 1

Comment: If `s` is negative you have to divide by -1